# Proving that $\det (A^2 - I) < 0 \Rightarrow \lambda \in (-1,1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Let $A$ be real square matrix. If $\det (A^2 - I) < 0$, then $A$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda \in (-1,1)$.

How to prove this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Use the intermediate value theorem. And you should probably state that $A$ is a real matrix.

Comment: @DanielFischer, well said, please consider making it into an answer.

Comment: Can we assume $A$ to be symmetric?

Comment: We can, but the problem applies to any real square matrix.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hint :

$\det(A^2-I)<0\Rightarrow \det(A+I)\cdot \det(A-I)<0$

Consider $f(x)=\det(A+xI)$ and consider case of $\det(A+I)>0$ and $\det(A-I)<0$

- What is $f(1)$
- What is $f(-1)$

Use Intermediate value theorem for this $f(x)$ and complete the rest...

Comment: This is really the best possible answer.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus : Thank you so much... I feel happy only if  OP understand this and complete the rest...

Comment: The only thing I see from you decomposition is that eigenvalue cannot be $\pm 1$.

Comment: The same: 1 isn't eigenvalue of A. Sorry but nothing more.

Comment: I should have been more clear... It is not that $\det(A+I)<0$ or $\det(A-I)>0$ but actually both... I mean either $\det(A+I)<0;\det(A-I)>0$ or $\det(A+I)>0;\det(A-I)<0$

Comment: Yes, I understand this. But what's the relationship between sign of determinant of such sum/difference and eigenvalues?

Comment: I am seeing little gap which can not be easily cleared... I need some time to make this more clear...

Comment: @Yaldc : please see the edit...

Comment: fantastic answer

Comment: I got it! Actually, it's simple. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @monalisa : Thank you :)

Comment: @Yaldc : You are welcome :)

Comment: @UneFemmeDouce : It is just a polynomial in $x$ so is continuous..

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: We have, if $\lambda_i$, $1 \le i \le n$ denote the eigenvalues of $A$, $$ \det(A^2 - 1) = \prod_{i=1}^n (\lambda_i^2 - 1) $$

Comment: So what if some $\lambda_i$ are purely imaginary? (The characteristic polynomial of a real matrix need not split into real linear factors.)

Comment: If $\lambda =\mu + i\nu$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, $\bar\lambda$ also is and the corresponding factors give $|\lambda_i^2 - 1|^2 \ge 0$

Comment: Let $n = 2$. $(\lambda^2_1 -1)(\lambda^2_2 -1) < 0 \Rightarrow$ one multiplier must be negative, the other must be positive $\Rightarrow \lambda^2_1 -1 < 0  \wedge \lambda^2_2 -1 > 0$. From the 1st inequality we get $|\lambda_1| < 1$ which is exactly what I need, but from the 2nd inequality: $\lambda_2 >1$ which is wrong. Did I make a mistake somewhere?